# Laravel 4.2 artisan missing commands [optimize, clear-compiled etc]

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-artisan

I have developed a project using laravel 4.2

Today I need to run different commands of artisan.

These commands are available on my local development machine, but same project on server getting error commands not exists.

**Live server artisan commands list**
[image]

**Local server artisan commands list**
[image]

**Problem:** Why there is difference of commands on same project?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the composer version difference on the machines

Comment: its the same version of composer on both machine. I have confirmed it.

Comment: some missing artisan commands are, optimize, clear-compiled etc